# Carbon PHP equal or greater than not returning true

Tags: php, php-carbon

I'm trying to do a comparison between date & times in Carbon PHP 2. For context, my server is in `Europe/London` timezone, and a user has the functionality to set their own timezone, thus my `$timezone` variable. My Laravel 8 project default timezone config is `Europe/London` too.

When a user provides a start time, I store the date & time as a date field in my DB, but obviously the day, month and year would always be wrong at the point my code runs, thus why we override these with the current day.

Still though, you can see from my output that their time is greater than the start time, but my `if` statement never runs, why?

```php
$timezone = 'Asia/Tokyo';

$startTime = Carbon::parse('2022-08-01 05:00:00');
$theirTime = Carbon::parse(Carbon::now())->setTimezone($timezone);
$ourTime = Carbon::parse($theirTime)->setTimezone('Europe/London');     

$startTime = $startTime->day($theirTime->day);
$startTime = $startTime->month($theirTime->month);
$startTime = $startTime->year($theirTime->year);

echo "their time: $theirTime ----- start: $startTime";

if ($theirTime >= $startTime) {
  echo 'run now';
} else {
  echo 'do not run';
}
```

output is:

> their time: 2022-08-05 05:16:27 ----- start: 2022-08-05 05:00:00do not run

05:16:27 is greater than 05:00:00 so should output **run now**, what am I missing?

[image]

Comment: What's the timezone of the server, or print out the timezone of the $startTime.  I believe it's still going to use the timezone in the comparison, so the numbers alone don't tell the whole story.

Comment: The server is `Europe/London`. Sure, so what do I need to modify in the `if` statement to match the code attached as everything above the `if` statement is working as intended.

Comment: You parse the date using the default timezone and then change the timezone but the original time will be parsed in the default timezone so set the default timezone before parsing

Comment: You are making life hard for yourself. Convert both times to UTC then compare.

Comment: Or even better, use unix timestamps for everything. and on client side, convert the unix timestamp to datetime with JS (automatically uses their timezone (browser or mobile timezone)) and you will remove all complexity (except readability from database)

Comment: @N69S The problem here is that the user wants some action at eg 05:00  This cannot be held as a timestamp.  It needs to be converted to UTC then stored in the database ( (my preference).  If everything is held in UTC (neither London time) it makes comparisons easy.  Apply the user's timezone when displaying any date/time

Comment: If you are working with different time zones, then my suggestion is to convert all timestamps to a standard format, ie UTC.

Comment: I'm not sure I can convert it to UTC, because the entry stored in the DB would always be `Europe/London`, and as such, in some timezones like `Asia/Tokyo` whilst near the end of the day in the UK, would be the next day in Tokyo, so, when converting the user's time to UTC would result in the days (not just time) being the same. @Rohit Gupta

Comment: @Snapey spot on here. Yes, the field is datetime, but the front-end component only accepts time, and, for comparisons I need to include both date & time, thus why I'm overriding the day, month and year.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you would run the server in UTC.  When the user enters Wake me up at 6am you need to know 6am in what timezone, so need to store the timezone with the 6am or with that user's profile - whatever makes more sense in your application. But it would be a problem to search the database for each user's wakeup time in their own timezone so for activities like this, convert the time to UTC before storing it.

Then if the user wanted waking at 6am, this might be 18:00 utc but that would not matter. When the 'wakeup' time is the same as the server's current time, wake the user up and tell them "this is your `$wakeup)->tz($user->timezone)` wakeup".

Regarding your specific situation, you want to know if now() in Tokyo is greater than the time on the DB record, however you can only look at the H:m in the stored value;

```
$theirTime = Carbon\Carbon::parse('2022-03-01 05:00'); // get this from DB

// our reference point
$current = now()->tz('Asia/Tokyo');

$target = now()->tz('Asia/Tokyo');
$target->hour = $theirTime->hour;
$target->minute = $theirTime->minute;
$target->second = 0;

if($current->gte($target)) {
  echo 'overdue';
} else {
  echo 'Not due';
}
```

Comment: Cool, so the suggestion here is to convert to UTC time?

Comment: This answer does not need to convert to UTC, but as a general idea, better to work in one timezone.  The place where this becomes difficult is people that want 'daily' reports where everyone's days start at a different time.  I don't think there is a simple rule.

Comment: Exactly, that's exactly what my Stackoverflow question is about. Because users can select, say, Tue, Wed, Fri @ 13:00, so on each of those days at that time they'd expect it to run on their timezone, but since my server is in Europe, it wouldn't run.

Comment: Its not hard to solve, as I have shown.

Answer (score 0):

You can use carbon `gte()` method

```
if ($theirTime->gte($startTime)) {
  echo 'run now';
} else {
  echo 'do not run';
}
```

as for why it says "do not run", it is because "2022-08-05 05:16:27 GMT+1" comes before "2022-08-05 05:00:00 GMT" and carbon carbon converts itself to integer (unix timestamp) in the comparisation.
I cant give you a complete example because you did not define what `$timezone` is in your question.

If you want to compare the times as strings directly (and have total faith in your control of timezones you can

```
if ($theirTime->format('H:i:s') >= $startTime->format('H:i:s')) {
  echo 'run now';
} else {
  echo 'do not run';
}
```

Comment: Timezone is the user's timezone. It's what's set on their profile. In my example, I used `Asia/Tokyo` but able to reproduce the issue in others such as `Europe/London` (my timezone)